# Non-functioning of the application when adding Facebook Like Button

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-like

I am working on adding Facebook Like button to the application everything is normal but the problem when running the application and do not know what exactly is the problem

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    NavigationView mNavigationView;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "notifyId";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    String reg_cgm_id;
    static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Settings.sdkInitialize(this);
        LikeView likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.like_view);
        likeView.setObjectId("https://m.facebook.com/DZ.4.EverR");
        likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.STANDARD);
        likeView.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);
        likeView.setHorizontalAlignment(LikeView.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        }

        //show admob banner ad
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int error) {
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_drawer) ;

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, new FragmentRecent()).commit();

        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                //setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.drawer_recent) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, new FragmentRecent()).commit();
                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.drawer_category) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, new FragmentCategory()).commit();
                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.drawer_favorite) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, new FragmentFavorite()).commit();
                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.drawer_rate) {
                    final String appName = getPackageName();
                    try {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appName)));
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appName)));
                    }
                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.drawer_more) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getString(R.string.play_more_apps))));
                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.drawer_setting) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

                return false;
            }

        });

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

        // init analytics tracker
        ((Analytics) getApplication()).getTracker();

        // GCM
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            String reg_cgm_id = getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());
            Log.i(TAG, "Play Services Ok.");
            if (reg_cgm_id.isEmpty()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Find Register ID.");
                registerInBackground();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // analytics
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // analytics
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mAdView.pause();
        super.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mAdView.resume();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mAdView.destroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        LikeView.handleOnActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(MainActivity.this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, 9000).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        String registrationId = preferences.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
        // app version.
        int registeredVersion = preferences.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Analytics version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;

    }

    private void registerInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
                    }
                    reg_cgm_id = gcm.register(getString(R.string.google_api_sender_id));
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + reg_cgm_id;
                    Log.d(TAG, "ID GCM: " + reg_cgm_id);
                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend();
                    storeRegistrationId(MainActivity.this, reg_cgm_id);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                }
                return msg;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {

            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);

    }

    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;

        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }

    private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", reg_cgm_id));
        new HttpTask(null, MainActivity.this, Config.SERVER_URL + "/register.php", nameValuePairs, false).execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Going to need a lot more information that than. You say it doesn't work, but HOW doesn't it work? Is it non-responsive? Does it crash? Does clicking the button not work?

Comment: When the application starts showing message application has stopped

Comment: So that's a crash. What does your LogCat say?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: What's the whole thing?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.solodroid.materialwallpaper/com.solodroid.materialwallpaper.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.widget.LikeView.setObjectId(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Can you please add these details to the question it self? Without these details it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the important part of your log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
    'void com.facebook.widget.LikeView.setObjectId(java.lang.String)' 
    on a null object reference at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
```

It's saying that you're trying to call the method setObjectId on a LikeView that is null. So, step through that part of the code and figure out why the LikeView is null.

Comment: Well, and how do I solving this problem

Comment: Have you actually added the LikeView to your layout file? Does it have the id of like_view?